# Can I use Firebase Dynamic Links for a web app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-dynamic-links, referrals

I don't see any option for Web under "receiving dynamic links" in [Firebase Dynamic links page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/).

> Without the SDK, there's no way to connect a post-install user with a pre-install click.

I have a desktop app that runs on node.js like a web app, using nw.js. What I'm trying to do is create referral links for users.  After someone clicks a referral link, I need to be able to track his referrer. But the problem is that link is only going to take him to the download page, after he downloads and opens up the app for the first time, how can I reach his referrer info? The desktop app has no connection with the website that users download from.

I understand that this can be done with Dynamic Links SDK but can I use that SDK in a web app?(desktop app actually but runs with HTML/node.js)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The post-install deeplinking in Dynamic Links is just for Android and iOS - so there isn't an equivalent for a desktop app.